# Возможно ли настроить email уведомления в интерфейсе azure, при сбоях архивации в хранилище?

Tags: windows-server, резервное-копирование, azure, уведомления

Зарегистрировал аккаунт в azure, создал хранилище, установил agent для windows server. Хочу получать email в случае сбоя архивации, или превышении квоты на хранилище, короче хочу быть в курсе всего, не входя в веб-интерфейс управления.

Лог архивации, я нашел только в журналах на стороне агента, и я в принципе знаю как можно настроить уведомления на стороне агента, но если есть возможность получать уведомления из хранилища azure, то для меня такое решение будет более выгодным.

Я также понимаю, что это немного нелогично, ведь план архивации задается на стороне агента, но ввиду большого количества настроек в интерфейсе azure я не исключаю, что уведомления возможно инициировать и на стороне хранилища.

Comment: Я не понял вопрос... Что имеется ввиду под архивацией? Ты используешь Azure Recovery Services или нечто самодельное (к примеру какие-нибудь PowerShell скрипты итд.)?

Answer (score 1):

Если ты используешь Azure Recovery Services то я нашел по запросу "Azure Backup Services notification" в гугле пару интересных блог-постов на эту тему:

- [Introducing Email notifications for Azure Site Recovery](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-email-notifications-azure-site-recovery/)
- [Azure Backup Email Notification](https://proximagr.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/azure-backup-email-notification/)

Надеюсь, что это поможет.

Comment: Добрый день! Принял правку, вроде нигде не нашел, но на всякий случай переспрашиваю — текст же не скопирован откуда-нибудь? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/52114

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Нет, тест самописный с опорой на несколько различных ресурсов.

Comment: Ок, это хорошо. )